# Binding custom properties while setting custom dependency property in style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Here I have a custom dependency property and I set it in this way. The thing I want to do is to bind its own properties to controls that you can see in code. I have tried `RelativeResource` as you can see in code but nothing is shown.
Do I need to use `ControlTemplate`to declare target type or is there any way to solve this problem?

**ResourceDictionary**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type infiniteReservoir:PressureSource}">
        <Setter Property="PropertyPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScrollViewer >
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="Pressure:" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox/>
                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <TextBlock Text="Temperature:" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox/>
                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <TextBlock Text="Label:" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Media:" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ToolTip}"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Fluid Zone ID:" Grid.Row="4"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Port Name:" Grid.Row="5"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Model**

```
#region PropertyPanel
public ScrollViewer PropertyPanel
{
     get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(PropertyPanelProperty); }
     set { SetValue(PropertyPanelProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyPanelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyPanel", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(DesignerItem));
#endregion
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`TemplatedParent` only works in a ControlTemplate.

I suspect that what you want is this:

```
<Grid 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type infiniteReservoir:PressureSource}}}">
```

As a side note, it's usually considered poor practice to bind DataContext, since that can often have unexpected side effects. You can instead use the RelativeSource in each of the bindings on the children:

```
<TextBlock Text="Label:" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type infiniteReservoir:PressureSource}}}"
        />

    <TextBlock Text="Media:" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="3" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Text="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type infiniteReservoir:PressureSource}}}"
        />
```

Comment: I have tried to use AncestorType as well but unfortunatelly it didn't work.

Comment: @YektaMirkan That certainly is unfortunate. I guess the next step is that you provide enough code to replicate the issue.